# Issue with applying str_length to a dataframe

Tags: r, stringr

I created a simple R Script that is run on a monthly basis by colleagues.

This script brings in a fairly chunky RDS file that has around 2.6M observations and 521 variables.

Against this file the following two commands are run:

```
Latest$MFU <- substr(Latest$SUB_BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE, 1, 2)
Latest$LENGTH <- str_length(Latest$POLICYHOLDER_COMPANY_NAME_LAST_NAME)
```

This script has run perfectly for the last three years, but today, for some reason, it is now failing for all three people tasked to run it and has indeed fallen over for myself too.

The error message received is

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.0 Mb

At first I assumed that their computers were running out of memory, or they were not using 64Bit R, or some other reason such as not restarting their computers, etc.

It turns out though that they have plenty of memory available, have restarted their computers, are using 64 Bit R in R Studio and all are using different versions of R Studio/R.

I tried running the process myself, my computer has 32GB of Ram and 768GB of Hard Drive space free. I am getting the same error message.......

So, must be a corrupt source file I figure. Try last months file which all ran just fine last month for everyone and same error.

Maybe just try stringr package instead then, move around the problem that way. Nope, no dice, exact same error message.

I have to admit I'm stumped. I have tried gc(), tried previous versions of the file, tried cutting the file in half and running it that way, it just flat out refuses to run.

Anyone know of an alternative to stringr/base R commands to get the length of a character string as a new variable and to get a substring as a new variable?

Comment: It seems to be a memory overflow problem. Which of the two commands is raising the error? Also you are using base data.frame class which I do not recommend when data gets big. Did you try with **data.table**?

Comment: What about  ```rm(list=ls())``` before running, and ```memory.limit(size = 16265*4) ``` (or another big number) ?

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti Both commands generate the error, albeit with slightly different vector size warnings. 

It is a data.frame as opposed to data.table, I appreciate that it is bigger than the normal dataset, but the RDS is only around 400MB so my head said that it should not need to be a data.table, still I'll certainly take a look into it now!

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington changing the Memory Limit did the trick.

I'm intrigued though, if the resource was available, which on my computer especially it must be, why would it bug out moaning about vector sizing?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington, can't seem to find how to mark your answer as correct. But problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `rm(list=ls())`  before running, and `memory.limit(size = 16265*4)` (or another big number) ?